# 'try' 'catch' is not working in this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to get a value from the back-end by using PHP. In my case sometimes this PHP request does not get anything back. When that happens I want to get a value from local storage. I use:

```
try {
    var operator = <?=$this->shopRequest[operator]?>;
}
catch() {
    var operator = sessionStorage.getItem('operator');
}
```

Why is this not working? I get the error

> "';' is missing"

in the console, because the PHP request does not return anything.

Comment: I think you have to specify the exception you want to catch. You cant call "catch" without arguments.

Comment: You shouldn't mix php and js like that. Make an ajax request.

Comment: Can you give an example of that?:$

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with argument in `catch`?

And add an apostrophe if your value is a string for JavaScript and PHP code.

```
try {
    var operator = "<?=$this->shopRequest['operator']?>";
} 
catch (e) {
    var operator = sessionStorage.getItem('operator');
}
```

The key is a string, and you must to add an apostrophe:

```
<?=$array['key']?>
```